# How to replace a string in one file with a variable assigned from another file (array?)

Tags: python, arrays, regex, sed

I have two files and I would like to use one to replace strings in another file. The first (Names.txt) looks like this:

```
S_AA_45_biomass[c]  AA-biomass_c    
S_B10[c]    L-Isoleucine-biomass_c  
S_B11[c]    L-Leucine-biomass_c 
S_B12[c]    L-Lysine-biomass_c  
S_B13[c]    L-Methionine-biomass_c  
S_B14[c]    L-Phenylalanine-biomass_c
S_cpd00322[c]   L-Isoleucine_c
```

where column 1 corresponds to the strings in the second file and column 2 is what I would like to change those strings to. File 2 (Reactions.txt) looks like this:

```
B10_c   L-Isoleucine biomass reaction   S_cpd00322[c]  -> S_B10[c]      0     0.00  1000.00   0.00
```

and what I want is an output that looks like this:

```
B10_c   L-Isoleucine biomass reaction   L-Isoleucine_c  -> L-Isoleucine-biomass_c       0     0.00  1000.00   0.00
```

I was trying to write a for loop using sed to replace each string:

```
for i in `cat Names.txt `; do cat Reactions.txt | grep -F `echo $i | cut -f1` | sed 's/`echo $i | cut -f1`/`echo $i | cut -f2`/' >>output.txt; done
```

Apart from the fact that this doesn't work because of the special characters in the Names.txt file and also because it replaces only one word on each line before writing the results to output.txt, both files are over 2000 lines long so this isn't a very efficient approach. I was thinking an array might be the way to go but far from certain about that. Not too fussy about the approach, just after a result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
    a[$1] = $2;
    next
} {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
       printf (($i in a)? a[$i] : $i) ((i<NF)? OFS : ORS)
}' Names.txt Reactions.txt

B10_c L-Isoleucine biomass reaction L-Isoleucine_c -> L-Isoleucine-biomass_c 0 0.00 1000.00 0.00
```

Comment: This looks great but maybe I wasn't clear about where the tabs should be in the Reactions.txt file. The input should look like: 

    B10_c<tab>L-Isoleucine biomass reaction<tab>L-Isoleucine_c  -> L-Isoleucine-biomass_c<tab><tab>0<tab>0.00<tab>1000.00<tab>0.00

and I'd like to keep the tabs in these positions in the output file.

Comment: Ah bugger, thanks for noticing! Yes, the input should look like:  B10_c<tab>L-Isoleucine biomass reaction<tab>S_cpd00322[c]  -> S_B10[c]<tab><tab>0<tab>0.00<tab>1000.00<tab>0.00

and the Names.txt is a 2 column tab separated file too :

S_AA_45_biomass[c]<tab>AA-biomass_c

Comment: If 2nd file is using tab as delimiter then it must have tab before and after `->` also.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance but I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean I need change the 2nd file to have tabs before and after the `->`? If so, that's not going to work because the number of space separated reactants in that third column can vary and so would produce lines with different numbers of fields. I was hoping you might be able to modify that first script you wrote so it will conserve the tab delimited fields in the output.

Comment: No code or script will be able to work with a non-structured data like that where you have tab sometimes and space sometimes as a delimiter and still want to preserve each and every space in output.

Comment: I know we aren't meant to say thanks here but thanks. Very helpful. In the end I just cut out the third field of my input file and saved it as a new file and then used your script on that. I then pasted the original input file and the output file together and used awk to print out the fields I wanted to a new file.